# Is generating an RSA key with password and then stripping it off more secure than no password at all?

Tags: openssl, rsa, passphrase

Some time ago I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13901578/1338292) on SO; it asks how to remove the passphrase from an existing RSA key using a PHP equivalent to the existing `openssl rss` command.

I've posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901692/1338292) with the solution, but inside the comment thread the OP claimed the following:

> Encrypted key, which is later decrypted offers way better security than not encrypted at generation. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901578/php-equivalent-to-openssl-rsa-command/13901692#comment19156312_13901692)

To me that sounds like total BS; how could a key become more secure by generating it with a passphrase and then stripping it off?

But perhaps there's a valid reasoning behind this "fact"?

Comment: Could be one extra source of entropy, I suppose, for the CSPRNG, depending on how the CSPRNG is implemented, but beyond that, I think it's BS too. And even the "extra source of entropy" thing is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

`Disa` would be referring to the fact that if an attacker steals the encrypted key, they also need to steal the passphrase securing the key.

So `Disa` is referring to operational security instead of mathematical security. The encrypted key is not more mathematically secure - the level of entropy hasn't changed from the viewpoint of a brute force attack<sup>1</sup>. But the theft or copy of the hard drive will not necessarily lose the key to the attacker as the passphrase might be never be stored on the computer; outside of its own password manager.

<sub>1. Unless the initial entropy of the key pair was *so bad* that encrypting the key temporarily adds more entropy...</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Within OpenSSL, the exact same code is used to generate a RSA key pair, regardless of what is done afterwards with that key, e.g. whether it is stored in a file with or without some additional encryption layer.

Note, though, that private keys are sensitive objects; you shall strive to let them be written to a physical medium as rarely as possible. This is, generically, a problem for applications which wrap around the `openssl` command-line utility, because that utility tends to create *files*. An application might wish to generate a key pair in RAM, and use it, and maybe store the private key "elsewhere", but if the application relies on calling `openssl`, then a copy of the private key is likely to make it to some hard disk. **In that situation**, ensuring that the spurious copy is encrypted (with a fat random passphrase that is kept in RAM only) can improve security. In such a scenario, it would be better, though, to use OpenSSL, *the library*, directly, instead of the command-line tool (which has always been more of a debug helper anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (even if it's not obvious in Disa's note), it seems this can be more secure mainly if the key is not generated on the system where it will be used later (or if you will need to store a backup of the key somewhere).

In such case, the key will be written on the file system where it has been generated, which leaves traces even after usual file deletion, then the key will need to be transmitted on the destination system, either by network or any other mean (removable media, etc.), which both leaves traces and can be potentially intercepted.
You have better for this traces and potential interception risk to affect an encrypted version of the key than a clear one, even if the destination server will actually use a clear version.

Therefore, I think that this merely brings more security in the key handling process than in the key itself which remains the same, would have it be generated encrypted or not.